# Can't update trigger because of activity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, trigger, concurrency

Trying to add a line to a trigger that is attached to a table that is constantly in use

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[name_of_trigger] ON [dbo].[name_of_table] AFTER UPDATE
BEGIN

   IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN() in ('username')   RETURN

....somecode

END
```

Getting deadlocked and the only solution appears to be retrying every couple of seconds, which so far hasn't worked. Is there any other way to get my if condition in other than hitting F5 and hoping it works?

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Schedule a maintenance window.

Comment: [`SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186736.aspx)

Comment: Hello @JonSeigel, thank you for the hint, but basically even with the deaklock priority set higher for my session, I was still unable to get to a point where I had access to the table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you issue an `ALTER TRIGGER` statement, that process will attempt to acquire a SCH-M (schema modification) lock on the table object as well as the trigger object.  This is an extremely low-concurrency lock and will cause the expected blocking that you're running into.

See [this reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) for a chart on lock compatibility.  For referencing sake, here is the chart linked directly from that document:

[image]

As you can see, that SCH-M lock will conflict and cause a concurrency blocker.

Much like anything that can cause an interruption, or be blocked itself, I'll have to agree with the comment above (from David Crowell).  You simply need to find a time when there is little to no activity on these objects.

Comment: I wish a maintenance window were possible, but lets just assume that someone did something in production that needs to be rolled back. Guess they will have to wait and deal with the consequences.